# parsing returned data in success function never works

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'dialog.php',
    data: {
        champion_name:champion_name
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
        var dataStr = $(data).find('h2').html();
        $('#champImg').find('div').html(dataStr);

    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

I tried to parse returned data in success function because I need to append some elements in one certain div and other elements in other div.

However, `$(data).find('h2').html()` never works.
I tried every possible way including changing `dataType` to `html`, but it is working.

The returned data is valid because I see it alerts html codes from `dialog.php` successfully. Only `$(data).find('h2').html()` does not work!

Comment: Can you show us what data it returns?

Comment: <img class='style2' border='2' src='$imgPath' style='width:165px;height:232px;'><h2>hello</h2>                                I am just using this simple code to see if parsing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because there's no outer element and the selection therefor returns two elements. Find searches then children of the current element but your selection returns two elements one for the `image` and one for the `h2` neither with a `h2`-child

if the html had been

```
<div>
   <img class='style2' 
        border='2' 
        src='$imgPath' 
        style='width:165px;height:232px;'>   
   <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

it would work.

if you can't/won't change the returned html you can change the success handle to

```
function(data){
  alert(data);
  var dataStr = $(data)[1].html();
  $('#champImg').find('div').html(dataStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery `filter` method instead of `find`:

```
var dataStr = $(data).filter("h2").html();
```

Here's an example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zWHa/